# Creating a DataFrame by passing a NumPy array, with a datetime index and labeled columns:

Tags: python, pandas

On running a code, getting a following error:-

**'list' object is not callable**

```
dates = pd.date_range('20190101', periods=6)
dates

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Expected output:-

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2013-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
2013-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2013-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
2013-01-04  0.721555 -0.706771 -1.039575  0.271860
2013-01-05 -0.424972  0.567020  0.276232 -1.087401
2013-01-06 -0.673690  0.113648 -1.478427  0.524988
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, which line is throwing an error?

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.random.randn` generates an array of the shape you provide (in your case `(6,4)` filled with random floats sampled from a univariate “normal” (Gaussian) distribution of mean 0 and variance 1.

To get the year 2013, you should change the value in `date_range` function to `'20130101'`.

Also, the code snippet that you provided gives no error. So, perhaps you are getting an error because of some other code snippet. Anyway, here is what I think you're looking for:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=6)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
```

It gives the following output:

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly correct. If you execute it right after restarting your kernel it is bound to run. The error you are getting refers to the `list` function you have used to convert `string` 'ABCD' to list. Most likely, you have used list as an `object` name somewhere else, and this object is still in memory and overriding the list function.